Postman throws error when accessing http://103.180.163.187:8000/ but gives a response for http://0.0.0.0:8000/
I am implementing FastAPI and Uvicorn for the first time. I have already integrated FastAPI with my python code. I am running it on a remote server. It contains one GET and one POST request. I ran it using the command:
uvicorn main:app --reload 
It runs fine. Now I wanted to host it on the same remote server as a system service using Uvicorn since I have seen that it is possible. I followed the following steps:

Created a service file using the command, sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/uvicorn.service.
Added the following content in it:

"[Unit]
Description=Uvicorn Server

[Service]
User=my_name
Group=my_name
WorkingDirectory=dir/where/my/code/is/present
ExecStart=/my_name/venv/bin/uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
"


Ran the following commands:

sudo systemctl enable uvicorn
sudo systemctl start uvicorn

What I found out was the uvicorn service was running fine. So I wanted to check in POSTMAN. The Problem I am facing now is when I do GET or POST on http://0.0.0.0:8000/, it works fine as expected (getting the results), but when I do GET or POST on http://103.180.163.187:8000/, it shows a connection ERROR. It is displayed as so :

I am sorry if it seems silly but please do let me know what points i have missed and how to fix this error. I want it such that my requests go through when i ping the IP address and not 0.0.0.0.
I tried allowing access to my port 8000 on the remote server using sudo ufw allow 8000 also but still the problem isn't resolved. Could there be any other reason why this is happening ?

that could be your firewall or your network configuration.

checked those and verfied both the remote server and local machine. still not working
